# Запретить отключение экрана Windows при помощи Python

Tags: python, windows

Написал скрипт для захвата и записи монитора при помощи ffmpeg. Встал вопрос, можно ли каким-то образом средствами Python запретить винде уходить в режим сна, а также выключать монитор. Имитировать нажатие клавиши? Или есть более хорошее решение?

Comment: [Эмуляция нажатия клавиш](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906925/). Можно делать это так, как делает PowerPoint - симулирует нажатие **F15**

Answer (score 3):

Например, использовать [powercfg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powercfg), которая есть в Windows, начиная с XP SP2. При старте захвата изобразить что-то вроде:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("powercfg -change -monitor-timeout-ac 0")
subprocess.call("powercfg -change -disk-timeout-ac 0")
subprocess.call("powercfg -change -standby-timeout-ac 0")
```

Установка в ноль означает "никогда не отключать", но можно ставить и очень большие значения. А после окончания - вернуть установки назад:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("powercfg -change -monitor-timeout-ac 10")
subprocess.call("powercfg -change -disk-timeout-ac 60")
subprocess.call("powercfg -change -standby-timeout-ac 120")
```

как вариант - создать свою схему "MY_SUPER_ACTIVITY" в Панели управления, где запретить выключение,  и вызывать ее:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("powercfg -SETACTIVE MY_SUPER_ACTIVITY")
```

а потом всё вернуть назад:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("powercfg -SETACTIVE SCHEME_BALANCED")
```